# jQuery - how to receive result from an inner ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am developing an web app in which the user will be able to identify the location from map by clicking on the map (I use **jquery 3.1**). The problem is that I have to make some ajax calls, one depend on other, and on the last call the result it's not returned as a whole (full array) and I received only a part of array.

The problem survives from **var a4**.

How I can make that a4 result to be send as a full array because I tried with deferred but with no expecting result?

```
var getLocDetails = function () {
    // Parse a web api based on user lat & lon
    var a1 = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=44.43588&lon=26.04745&accept-language=ro&format=json'
    });

    // Get osm_type & osm_id and parse another web service to get a XML document (Ex.: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/28240583)
    var a2 = a1.then(function (data) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/' + data.osm_type + '/' + data.osm_id
        })
    });

    // Get all 'ref' attribute from every 'nd' node from XML and make an array with this values
    var a3 = a2.then(function (data) {
        var osmChildren = data.documentElement.childNodes;
        var out = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < osmChildren.length; i++) {
            if (osmChildren[i].nodeName == 'way') {
                var wayChildren = osmChildren[i].childNodes;
                for (var j = 0; j < wayChildren.length; j++) {
                    if (wayChildren[j].nodeName == 'nd') {
                        var ndRef = Number.parseInt(wayChildren[j].getAttribute('ref'));
                        out.push(ndRef);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    });

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    // Based on array returned from a3, I am parsing every link like 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/ + nodeRef' to extract every lat and lon values for extreme points
    var a4 = a3.then(function (data) {
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        var out = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var nodeRef = data[i];
            var nodeUrl = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/' + nodeRef;

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: nodeUrl
            }).done(function (response) {
                var node = response.documentElement.firstElementChild;
                var lat = Number.parseFloat(node.getAttribute('lat'));
                var lng = Number.parseFloat(node.getAttribute('lon'));

                out.push([lat, lng]);
                defer.resolve(out);
            });
        }
        return defer.promise();
    });

    // When a4 is done, based his result, I have to have an array of lat & lon coordonates, but I recived only 1-2 coordonates even I have 10.
    a4.done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // Here I have to draw a polygon
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to handle the requests in an array, as what you are doing tends to resolve the callback for a4 before all are complete.

To do this we can use `$.when` function

```
var req = [];
// Based on array returned from a3, I am parsing every link like 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/ + nodeRef' to extract every lat and lon values for extreme points
var a4 = a3.then(function (data) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var out = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var nodeRef = data[i];
        var nodeUrl = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/' + nodeRef;

        req.push(
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: nodeUrl
            }).done(function (response) {
                var node = response.documentElement.firstElementChild;
                var lat = Number.parseFloat(node.getAttribute('lat'));
                var lng = Number.parseFloat(node.getAttribute('lon'));
                out.push([lat, lng]);
            })
       );
    }
    $.when.apply($, req).done(function(){
        return defer.resolve(out);
    });
    return defer.promise();
});
```